# Entry multilínea en tkinter (o Text con StringVar)

Tags: python, tkinter

Para una GUI, quiero crear un Entry de ttk de forma que acepte entradas más o menos grandes, por lo que debería ser multilínea.

```
wg = ttk.Entry(f_padre, textvariable=svar)
```

Intenté usar `tkinter.Text`, pero no permite el uso de `textvariable`, y es muy importante en mi programa, dado que la UI se "autoconstruye" y asume que todos los widgets tienen una.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que el Entry reciba múltiples líneas o de que el Text reciba textvariable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ninguna de las dos cosas es posible con los widgets estándar, el widget Entry solo permite entradas en una sola línea y de texto plano.

El widget `Text` es mucho más complejo, permitiendo no solo multiples líneas, sino texto enriquecido,incluidas imágenes y otros widgets y formateo mediante etiquetas, pero no acepta asociarse con una `StringVar` (que solo almacena texto plano).

No obstante, por ser posible, es posible. La idea básica es crear una clase derivada de `tkinter.Text` que acepte una `StringVar` y luego actualizar mutuamente ambos widgets cuando el contenido en alguno de ellos cambie. Por parte de la `StringVar` no hay problema ya que se puede monitorizar mediante `trace_add` y el modo `"write"`. El problema es que con el widget `Text` la cosa cambia porque no proporciona ningún método o evento para monitorizar la inserción o eliminación de contenido en tiempo real, de forma que no tenemos una forma adecuada de ir actualizando la variable según se escriba en el widget.

Una posible solución sería crear un wrapper sobre le método `get` de la `StringVar` que fuerce a tomar el contenido del widget cuando sea llamado. El problema es que hay casos dónde el método `get` no entra en funcionamiento, por ejemplo cuando se usa la variable para sincronizar el contenido de dos widgets.

Buscando una solución más imaginativa me he topado con [ésta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21565476/7131499) de, cómo no podía ser de otra forma el "gurú" de tkinter/tk en SO, [Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley) en SO. Su aproximación es crear un proxy a nivel de tcl que simplemente se encargue de emitir el evento que echábamos en falta cuando se inserte, elimine o modifique texto en el widget.

Dado que la respuesta es del 2014 y para Python 2, hay que modificar algunas cosas, por ejemplo el método `trace` está actualmente marcado como obsoleto. Dejo una versión actualizada y un ejemplo basado en la respuesta de Bryan que tiene todo el mérito en éste caso:

```
import tkinter as tk


class TextWithVar(tk.Text):
    '''A text widget that accepts a 'textvariable' option'''
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, textvariable=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self._textvariable = textvariable
        self._on_var_change()

        self.tk.eval('''
            proc widget_proxy {widget widget_command args} {

                # call the real tk widget command with the real args
                set result [uplevel [linsert $args 0 $widget_command]]

                # if the contents changed, generate an event we can bind to
                if {([lindex $args 0] in {insert replace delete})} {
                    event generate $widget <<Change>> -when tail
                }
                # return the result from the real widget command
                return $result
            }
            ''')

        self.tk.eval(f'''
            rename {self} _{self}
            interp alias {{}} ::{self} {{}} widget_proxy {self} _{self}
        ''')

        self.bind("<<Change>>", self._on_widget_change)

        if self._textvariable is not None:
            self._textvariable.trace_add(("write", "unset"), self._on_var_change)

    def _on_var_change(self, *args):
        '''Change the text widget when the associated textvariable changes'''
        text_current = self.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        var_current = self._textvariable.get()
        if text_current != var_current:
            self.delete("1.0", "end")
            self.insert("1.0", var_current)

    def _on_widget_change(self, event=None):
        '''Change the variable when the widget changes'''
        if self._textvariable is not None:
            self._textvariable.set(self.get("1.0", "end-1c"))


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent,  *args, **kwargs)
        self.var = tk.StringVar(self, value="Hola\nStackOverflow en Español")
        TextWithVar(self, textvariable=self.var).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        tk.Button(
            self, text="Imprimir variable",
            command=lambda: print(self.var.get())
            ).pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tendrás alguna idea de lo que hace al llamar `widget_proxy`? Es un concepto de Tcl mismo? Porque ahora lo estoy usando en otro contexto y al hacer un `self.config` me da error `_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "widget_proxy"`... Muy raro porque anteriormente me funcionaba